# How do I get fastboot/adb to find my device after a reboot?

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader

I am trying to unlock the bootloader of my Samsung Galaxy J7 Sky Pro using [this guide](https://rootmygalaxy.net/unlock-bootloader-android-using-fastboot-commands/).

If I do

```
> adb start-server
> adb devices
```

I get my device as connected, however when I then reboot into the bootloader using

```
> adb reboot bootloader
```

Everything works as I would suspect I get the boot screen with the extra text:

```
ODIN MODE (HIGH SPEED)
PRODUCT NAME: SM-2727VL
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
FAP LOCK: OFF
WARRANTY VOID: 0x0
QUALCOMM SECUREBOOT: ENABLE (CSB)
RP SWREV: S1, T1, R1, A4, P1
RP SWREV K 2, S 2
SECURE DOWNLOAD : ENABLE
download mode !!
```

Which seems ok to me.

However when run `adb devices` again the device is gone.  Of course if I try to run any `fastboot` command from this state it just sits and waits for a device.

```
< waiting for any device >
```

Even if I try killing and restarting the sever it doesn't find the device.

The same occurs running both on a Linux machine and an OSX machine.

What's going wrong here?  How do I get fastboot/adb to find my device after a reboot?

Comment: The article is just wrong. The correct title should be " Unlock Bootloader Of Any Android Device except Samsung devices" because Samsung device usually don't have a fastboot mode. Additionally Huawei device can't be unlocked anymore (another false fact in the article).

Comment: @Robert You have to forgive me for being a little incredulous, I'm seeing multiple articles that suggest to use fastboot even specifically on *samsung* phones.  Are you sure that this is the case for samsung.

Comment: Robert is right. [No fastboot](https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+fastboot+commands+site:android.stackexchange.com). A fastboot *like* environment is created by Odin and that's what is likely loosely called fastboot

Comment: Hello. That article doesn't mention that it is targeting your device. I guess you followed it because  of that generic  and deceptive heading. That article is next to useless (and dangerous too) for Samsung devices and  devices with Mediatek chipset. My suggestion is that you find a guide written for your device and than try following it. XDA forums are much better source for rooting than blogs or websites (a lot of Android content oriented websites writes whatever crap they can just to bring traffic)

Comment: @Firelord Thanks you for the suggestion.  I actually was reading a guide written for my device that linked instructing me to follow its directions.  I suppose that just goes to show the lack of quality on these websites.

Comment: sure about phone model? closest i can find is **SM-S727VL** (but no solution yet): [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3696757), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3629724)